# Typed interfaces and Spring4D

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, spring4d

I am trying to use typed interfaces and Spring4D, but have some issues with Resolving. Please review details below.

**DB Objects:**

```
unit u_DB;

type
  TDBObject = class
  public
    property ID: TGUID;
  end;

  TDBCRM = class(TDBObject)
  public
    property SOME_FIELD: TSomeType;
  end;
```

---

**Declarations:**

```
unit i_BaseDAL;

type
  {$M+}
  IBaseDAL<T: TDBObject, constructor> = interface
  ['{56D48844-BD7F-4FF8-A4AE-30DA1A82AD67}']
    procedure RefreshData();
    ....
  end;
```

---

```
unit u_BaseDAL;

type
  TBaseDAL<T: TDBObject, constructor> = class(TInterfacedObject, IBaseDAL<TDBObject>)
  public
    procedure RefreshData();
  ....
  end;
```

---

After that I was able to register the base IBaseDAL and IBaseDAL

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IBaseDAL<TDBObject>>;
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IBaseDAL<TDBCRM>>;
```

**Using in project:**

I need to resolve now IBaseDAL, but could not find how do it. Only below ugly approach work

```
DM := GlobalContainer.Resolve('i_BaseDAL.IBaseDAL<u_DB.TDBObject>@TBaseDAL<u_DBCRM.TDBCRM>').AsInterface as IBaseDAL<TDBObject>;
```

but I was hoping that below will work :) -

```
DM := GlobalContainer.Resolve(IBaseDAL<TDBCRM>);
```

Please advise how could it be resolved correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I just noticed that somehow the interface table does not contain generic interfaces so you have to explicitly register them as explained below.

<s>First you need to register an implementation and not just an interface.</s>

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TBaseDAL<TDBObject>>;
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TBaseDAL<TDBCRM>>;
GlobalContainer.Build;
```

The container will inspect the class you registered and register all implemented interfaces (except IInterface) so it will know about `IBaseDAL<TDBObject>` and `IBaseDAL<TDBCRM>`.

If your class might implement some interfaces you don't want the container to know you have to register explicit:

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IBaseDAL<TDBObject>, TBaseDAL<TDBObject>>;
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IBaseDAL<TDBCRM>, TBaseDAL<TDBCRM>>;
GlobalContainer.Build;
```

Then you can resolve:

```
GlobalContainer.Resolve<IBaseDAL<TDBCRM>>;
```

By the way, are you sure your class definition should not be as follows?

```
type
  TBaseDAL<T: TDBObject, constructor> = class(TInterfacedObject, IBaseDAL<T>)
```

Comment: I was trying class definition in both variants as I described and in your variant, but without changes. Also I tried your recommendation, but got the same error: `[dcc32 Error] fr_CRM.pas(231): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Resolve' that can be called with these arguments`

Comment: As you mentioned in the other question you called Resolve wrong. You did not type angle brackets but round brackets. Generics require angle brackets (`<` `>` and not `(` `)`)

Comment: Thanks, but with `<` `>` I got `[dcc32 Error] frm_CRM.pas(32): E2010 Incompatible types: "i_BaseDAL.IBaseDAL<u_DB.TDBObject>" and "i_BaseDAL.IBaseDAL<u_DB.TDBCRM>"`

Comment: Not sure, I rechecked advises from Stefan and looks like everything is OK. I am about to prepare test project and push to Google group